# ¿Como saber si se ha ejecutado un AJAX y si se ha ejecutado con éxito?

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui

estoy haciendo una función de arrastrar y soltar un elemento para eliminar, en un div especifico (draggable y droppable), y quisiera hacer que cuando suelte el elemento en el div droppable y se ejecuta AJAX, si es verdadera, me haga una animación, sino que me haga un revert: true. Para eso, no lo puedo hacer en el droppable, sinó en el draggable (en el **revert** o en el **stop**), además nosé si lo planteo bien, así que pensé que en el draggable en el **stop:**,(o en el rever, nose) hacer una function que si se ha ejecutado AJAX con exito, hacer tal función, sino hacer revert: true, **pero sin hacer petición** ya que hay otro AJAX en el droppable *drop:*. Dejo los códigos aquí:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#draggable_div").draggable({
    revert:true,
    start:function(){
      $(this).css({
        "position":"relative",
        "transform":"scale(0.8)",
        "z-index":"9999"
      });
    },
    stop:function(){
      $(this).css({
        "position":"relative",
        "transform":"scale(1)",
        "z-index":"9999"
      });
    }
  });
  $("#droppable_div").droppable({
    over:function(){
      $(this).css({
        "background":"rgba(237,28,36,0.2)"
      });
    },
    out:function(){
      $(this).css({
        "background":"red"
      });
    },
    desactive:function(){
      $(this).css({
        "background":"red"
      });
    },
    drop:function(){
    /*
    Petición AJAX
    */
    alert("Se hace una petición AJAX");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable_div{
  position:relative;
  height:0%;
  width:50%;
  background:blue;
  z-index:999;
}
#draggable_div p{
  font-size:3vw;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:10px;
}
#droppable_div{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:0%;
  top:200px;
  background:red;
}
#droppable_div p{
  font-size:3vw;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable_div">
  <p>Draggable</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable_div">
  <p>Droppable</p>
</div>
```

En realidad estoy un poco perdido y no se por donde tirar, pensé en hacer eso.

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. También es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Aqui te dejo una guía de cómo deberían ser los ejemplos: [mínimos, completos y verificables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer una petición por AJAX, se disparan eventos que te indicarán si se completó con éxito o no.

Dado que estás usando jQuery, te muestro un poco la estructura de cómo sería en ese caso.

Tomando el ejemplo dado por la [documentación de jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) y traduciendolo:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "la petición se ejecutó con éxito" );
    //aquí puedes ejecutar más cosas

  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "la petición se terminó de ejecutar, pero hubo un error" );
    //aquí puedes ejecutar más cosas

  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "la petición se terminó de ejecutar (no importa si fue con éxito o no). " );
    //aquí puedes ejecutar más cosas, que se ejecutarán ya sea que haya tenido éxito o no la petición.
  });
```

Normalmente yo uso `.done()` y `.fail()`, que permiten distinguir si tuvo éxito o no la petición. `.always()` se ejecuta siempre que se termina de procesar la petición, con o éxito o no.

Answer (score 0):

hice una funcion más fácil por la cual cuando lo ejecutas desaparece la actividad que has ejecutado pero, solo lo hace la primera vez que la página se ha cargado, la segunda no, y no se porque me hace eso.

```
    $("[id='actividades']").draggable({
  revert: true,
  start:function(event){
    $(this).css({
      "position":"absolute",
      "transform":"scale(0.5)",
      "z-index":"9999"
    });
    $(".div_eliminacion").animate({
      bottom:"0%"
    },700);
    $("[id='actividades']").mouseenter(function(){
      event1 = $("#identificador");
      event1.preventDefault();
    });
  },
  drag:function(){
    $("[id='actividades']").off("mouseenter");
  },
  stop:function(){
    $(this).css({
      "position":"relative",
      "z-index":"999",
      "transform":"scale(1)"
    });
    $(".div_eliminacion").animate({
      bottom:"-20%"
    },700);  
    $("[id='actividades']").mouseenter(function(){
      $("#identificador").text($(this).attr('lang'));
    });        
  }
});
$(".div_eliminacion").droppable({
  over:function(){
    $(".div_eliminacion").css("background","rgba(237,28,36,0.2)");
    $(".cls-1-tapa").css({
      "position":"absolute",
      "transform":"rotate(20deg) translate(-12px,-47px)"
    });
  },
  out:function(){
    $(".div_eliminacion").css("background","transparent");
    $(".cls-1-tapa").css({
      "position":"absolute",
      "transform":"rotate(0deg) translate(-15px,-24px)"
    });
  },
  drop:function(){
    var x = confirm("Quieres eliminar esta actividad?");
    var esto = $("#identificador").val();
    if (x== true) {
      var form = $("#form_identificador").serialize();
      var ID_1 = $("#identificador").val();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"eliminar_educaplay.php",
        data: form,
        success:function(e){
          if (e!=1) {
            $(".popup_no_eliminado").delay(500).slideDown("slow");
            $(".popup_no_eliminado").delay(1000).slideUp("slow");
          }else{
            $(".popup_eliminado").delay(500).slideDown("slow");
            $(".popup_eliminado").delay(1000).slideUp("slow");
            $("." + esto).remove();
          }
        }
      });
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  },
  deactivate:function(){
    $(".div_eliminacion").css("background","transparent");
    $(".cls-1-tapa").css({
      "position":"absolute",
      "transform":"rotate(0deg) translate(-15px,-24px)"
    });
  }
});
```

Gracias